# Date in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having to reverse engineer an Oracle query.  I'm familiar with SQL but not Oracle and I'm using SQL OPENQUERY to the linked Oracle server.  I've gone through the larger portions of the query and figured most of the syntax and getting results but when I get to the following in the where clause I get "missing expression" error. (simplified for clarity)

```
 SELECT USER_DATE
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE USER_DATE >= {1}
```

I can query the table and see that the column USER_DATE is indeed a date field so I don't understand the meaning of >= {1}.  This query came to me as "this is how the other dept uses this query, make it work for us" and I don't have access to this other dept.  Can someone explain how this supposedly works?

Comment: I believe this is a notation for input parameter, normally in oracle you write :param_name but if your info comes from listening to queries executed in the db it sometimes looks like that.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think it about it being parameter but that make sense in the larger scheme of the project

Answer (score 3):

The `{1}` is just a placeholder for an actual value. Once you've populated this with a proper date value it will run just fine like this:

```
SELECT USER_DATE
FROM TABLE
WHERE USER_DATE >= '01/01/2019'
```

You can also use the `to_date` function for a specific format:

```
SELECT USER_DATE
FROM TABLE
WHERE USER_DATE >= to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is a matter of default format of date in your remote Oracle database is different from the "other" database.  Most databases allow you to select date into string and also.conpare date to string.  The comparison implicitly converts string to date.

Most likely that implicit conversion is failing here.  Correct way would be to see if the parameter is a really a string and in what format is date presented there.  Then use to_date on right side around {1}.

To make it not error temporarily you can put to_char on left side.  Ofcourse your output will be incorrect but since SQL would run, you may be able to troubleshoot